# Send a name/value pair as object in Multipart using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data, http-put

In my code I have to make a MultipartForm-Data PUT request to update an object in the server, it ought to be Multipart as it is possible the user will send an image together with the data.

In order to do that, I am currently using Retrofit since it's a library I'm decently used to and it's working to send images to the server.

However, things have changed server-side and now one of the parameters that must be sent is:

```
{"step":
    {"type":"begin"}
}
```

However that's been proving to be surprisingly hard to do.

Things I have tried include passing it as a MultipartTypedOutput, a hand-typed String and a JSONObject converted to String, all of which gave me:

> retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request

The URL being used is correct, I've double checked with the person who maintains the server and it is reaching the server, but with an incorrect "step" object.

I've also tried passing it as NameValuePair, Map and HashMap, all of which gave me:

> retrofit.RetrofitError: Part body must not be null.

@FieldPart which looks to be perfect for this isn't compatible with Multipart, so is there a way to do this with Retrofit at all?

My current PUT method is as such:

```
@Headers({
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
    "Accept-Language: en-US"
})
@Multipart
@PUT("/0.1/user/{id}")
String updateUser(@Path("id") String userId, @Part("step") Map<String,String> type);
```

Where the Map type has been changed to all the types I mentioned before.

Comment: Please add the code which you are currently running as well as the response from the HTTP requests.

Comment: Sorry, after re-writing the question a couple times forgot to re-add the actual code. Question was edited to rectify that.

Comment: @Larpus if the below answer served your purpose, consider making it answer and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand what the issue is, as the "Part body must not be null" occurred even when trying out what Ankush mentioned.

Either way, I spoke to a few friends and a few contact expansions later, I got the following solution:

```
@Headers({
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
    "Accept-Language: en-US"
})
@Multipart
@PUT("/0.1/user/{id}")
String updateUser(@Path("id") String userId, @Part("step[type]") String type);
```

As far as I could find, this isn't mentioned anywhere in retrofit's documentation, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing it the correct way,just need some quick fix. I have two suggestions for you,
1. You can create a innerclass like this

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;

/**
* 
* @return
* The type
*/
public String getType() {
return type;
}

/**
* 
* @param type
* The type
*/
public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

}
```

In this case, your api will look like

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/0.1/user/{id}")
String updateUser(@Path("id") String userId, @Part("step") Example exp);
```

2. or, you can use the JsonObject, this is not the Apache JSONObject that you have already used. Its the google gson object which comes under package of `com.google.gson`. Here you need to do the following,
   JsonObject settingObject = new JsonObject();
   settingObject.addProperty("type", "begin");
   In this case, it will be,

   String updateUser(@Path("id") String userId, @Part("step") JsonObject obj);

This is all you need, btw you can also set the header for once and all, why bother defining it over an api ?

Comment: I apologize for taking so long, other parts of the project needed immediate attention. As it turns out, for whatever reason both methods still gave me the "Part body must not be null" error, but I did manage to solve it in another fashion.